# Extract words from a string and move them in an array

Tags: r, string, extract

I would like to extract some words form the following string in R. (I make them bold to become understandable) Then I need to move them to an array.

```
{\"AN\":\"**SC ANA**\",\"LOCC\":\"**Berlin**\"}
```

For example in above string I need SC ANA and Berlin to store in an array.

There are two constraints for me:
1- number of this fields may change, For example:

```
{\"AN\":\"**SC ANA**\",\"LOCC\":\"**Berlin**\",\"Nam\":\"**Alice**\"}
```

2- Also the length of each word may change. For example:

```
{\"AN\":\"**Bsc ANT**\",\"LOCC\":\"**Berlin LC**\",\"Nam\":\"**Alice JHV**\"}
```

Can anybody helps me?

Comment: You absolutely should be using a JSON _parser_ here, not a regex, not string extraction.  I don't know the exact R library, but someone else (maybe @akrun) should be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is JSON. You may use the `jsonlite` package rather than processing the strings by hand. For instance:

```
library(jsonlite)
fromJSON('{\"AN\":\"SC ANA\",\"LOCC\":\"Berlin\"}')
# $AN
# [1] "SC ANA"
# 
# $LOCC
# [1] "Berlin"
```

Comment: Thanks, it was amazing man!!
Just a question, Is the output in a single string or they are in two single strings? I mean that, for example how can I put "SC ANA" and "Berline" in a different variables or in a array.

Comment: The result, here, is a named list. See `help("fromJSON")` for finer control of the output. `as.data.frame(fromJSON('{\"AN\":\"SC ANA\",\"LOCC\":\"Berlin\"}'))` will give you a one row dataframe. Usually you may want to parse the whole JSON file at once, not string by string, and tweak the args of `fromJSON()` to get your desired output

Answer (score 1):

The string is in json format so you can do something like:

```
require(jsonlite)
require(dplyr)
str <- "{\"AN\":\"SC ANA\",\"LOCC\":\"Berlin\"}"

fromJSON(str) %>% unlist
```